# Where is the start menu folder for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

It's not "c:\Users\MyUserName\Start Menu\"

Answer (score 4):

All Users

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

Per Profile (unless redirected)

```
%SystemDrive%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```